# Adding a template to an extension point in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am a fan of adding extension points to my Eclipse RCP applications, as it makes them very modular.

Now, when you write the extension point schema, it is possible to add the documentation that will be shown in the Extension Point Selection wizard.  This wizard contains also an Available Templates section.  When a template is selected, some code is generated for you.  In this case I would like to use some AbstractClass as my base.

How do I add a template in this section?  I couldn't find this in the schema editor.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're after, are you talking about contributing an extra item to the extension point itself?

Comment: No, I've created an extension point for one of my plugins.  I've added documentation to this extension point so it is shown in the wizard.  Now I also want to add a template to auto-generate code that implements my extension point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at the org.eclipse.pde.ui.templates extension point.

With this you need to have a class that implements ITemplateSection, and associate it whit the extension point you want the template to be in.